# How to improve tethering while travelling in a train?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, tethering, data-connection, roaming

While traveling in trains, I like to surf the internet via the mobile browser or via laptop that is usb tethered with the android phone.

Many times I have realized that in rural areas with bad GSM network coverage, it is possible to get html pages on the phone whereas the laptop cannot get the page.

After switching to [2G-only](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9624/what-are-the-benefits-of-2g3g-mode/18086#18086) the surfing on the phone is much better now but surfing on the laptop is still bad.

I also read [why-usb-tethering-goes-off-after-a-while](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10016/why-usb-tethering-goes-off-after-a-while) but I do not think that my problem is caused by the network operator because surfing on phone still works.

Any ideas why this happens?
Are there any settings on the laptop to improve the situation?

I am using android 2.2 samsung galaxy fit and a win7-64bit laptop using the e+-gsm/umts phonenetwork

Comment: At a guess, Win7 isn't built to handle network interruptions like a phone OS would be.  I don't think we can help you with that.

Comment: does the same happens while Wifi tethering? It could be simply because many websites turns into mobile view, which loads much faster in places with no 3G, while the laptop insists on loading the full version.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your "User Agent" to `Android` or `iPhone`, this would speed up browsing on the Laptop. (There are several addons for every Browser out there which can do this)

But would only display the mobile sites, which are designed for use with a mobile device (e.g a Smartphone)